# c language - Submit a qsub job programmatically

Tags: c, linux, qsub

I want to programmatically submit a qsub job on a Linux in C.  This is the code I'm using and it is not working.

```
char command1[50];
chdir("/home/salah/proteins/1L2Y/try2_4changes/_1/");
strcpy(command1, "qsub submit.sh");
system(command1);
```

When I change the command (let's say to ./test.sh), it works just fine and does everything.  So I think the problem is in the qsub part.

Comment: What is the error message?  What would you type at the terminal to execute the job?  Is the program you're running running with the same environment that you normally use?  Is `qsub` an alias in your environment?  (If it is an alias, that's most of the trouble, probably.)

Comment: I type in terminal qsub submit.sh.  If I do it manually, it works.  I honestly don't know if qsub an alias in my environment.

Comment: Type `alias` and return, and see what it prints.  Or `alias | grep qsub`.  If you see `qsub=…`, then it is an alias.  If you don't, it probably isn't.  You may be able to use `which qsub` or `whereis qsub` to help, too.  (It could be a function, too; that would also cause problems.  You can use `typeset -f` to list functions; there may be a better alternative.)

Comment: ok, i got nothing in return when typed 'alias | grep qsub' , so I guess its not an alias.

Comment: When you run the program to submit the job, what error message is generated?  Have you checked the return value from the `chdir()` function?  Is there any particular reason you don't just run `system("qsub submit.sh")`?  Have you checked the return value from `system()`?  Have you checked the permissions on `submit.sh`?  Is `.` in your PATH?  If it works with `qsub ./test.sh`, does it work with `qsub ./submit.sh`?  Are you running the program from `cron` or `at` or something like that?

Comment: No error message is generated. chdir() works for sure because I tested it with other commands such as mkdir.  system("qsub submit.sh") is the same thing.  I am using putty though, so maybe its a permissions problem.

Comment: Since you haven't tested it with something like `if (chdir("…") != 0) { fprintf(stderr, "Failed to chdir()\n"); exit(1); }`, you don't know for sure it works.  Of course, it would be better to have the name in the error message, but that means defining a variable to hold the name, and then using the variable in the call to `chdir()` and in the call to `fprintf()` — since you wouldn't be silly enough to think of trying to write the name twice because that pretty much guarantees that one of them will be different from the other.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working if you aren't getting an error message?  Have you checked the queue status?

Comment: Do a `which qsub` in the shell. Try invoking qsub.from `system` using the absolute path.